# No Icons in Kentico Admin Page

Tags: icons, content-management-system, kentico

I'm very new to Kentico and just started using Kentico 11 for my companies CMS and have run into a lot of issues...most of which I've figured out by trial and error. The issue that comes up most often for me is that each time I create a new website with the wizard in the Admin page, no icons appear in either the dashboard or the applications list or on the top menu bar. It doesn't look like anyone has had this issue before, and I'm curious about how to fix it. I'm using IE 11.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, no icons appear anywhere in the dashboard, menu, or menu options. Please help with this issue.

Comment: Open Developer tools and reload the page and see if any console errors come up.

Comment: Where do I find developer tools? I've search the Kentico interface and there is no option for developer tools.

Comment: My apologies, apparently my brain wasn't ready for the day. I looked at the console errors in the developer tools, and saw the one warning I've included here: "DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337
CMSAdministration.aspx"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all your help. I found the answer and it was very basic and simple. For me the problem was Internet Explorer options not being enabled.

Talking with Kentico support is what tipped me off to this fix:
In IE 11, Go to Internet Options > Security Tab > Click Custom level > Scroll down until you get to Downloads > Under Font download check Enabled.

That was it. Like I said very simple, but on a development server where everything is disabled, it made a huge difference in performance of the Kentico interface.

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Do you know solution using Microsoft Edge also?

Answer (score 1):

these icons come from the font `/App_Themes/Default/Fonts/Core-icons.woff`. Check if it is loaded correctly.

Comment: Hi, have you seen this article already: https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/troubleshooting-dashboard-issues ? There are also couple of threads on DevNet on this topic. Does it happen in all browsers? Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Core-icons.woff is loaded correctly. And yes, I did follow the steps in the article with no resolve.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things can cause this:

- Most common, Kentico caches static objects pretty heavy, so try a simple CTRL + F5 to see if it refreshes things.
- If you have not granted access to the user running the website (granted on the app pool), there could be permissions issues with IIS not being able to get to the files it needs.  Typically you grant at least read and execute permissions at the /CMS level to the IIS_IUSRS user in the file system on your machine.
- Least common, the files weren't added during the install. To check this, run the installer again but in a different location like your Desktop, then spot check/compare a couple directories: /cms/cmsscripts and /cms/app_themes for any differences.

Comment: CTRL + F5 didn't work, IIS Permissions are set correctly, and Install Files are good to go. My template website started off like this as well (no icons), and overnight started displaying the icons magically. I got rid of it because I wanted to stop messing around and focus on my actual website. Now I'm back to having no icons, but it has been a couple of days and the icons still are not showing up.